# PyGtk3, ImageMenuItem image not showing

Tags: pygtk

i created a simple ImageMenuItem and added to menu but image of item not showing.

my code

```
self.image2 = gtk.ImageMenuItem("File1")
self.image2.set_image(gtk.Image.new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_APPLY, 1) ) # apply image not showing in this item
self.image2.connect("activate", self.imagex)
self.recent_menu.append(self.image2)
```

You can see my complete codes from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByGGW28GJgmoanFKUnMyaTI0bzQ?usp=sharing

Comment: If you post a complete executable example it will be much simpler for others to help you. My guess is that you need a show_all.

Comment: Oh. `image2.show_all` can solve my problem i will try. Thanks

Comment: `show_all` not working. perhaps icons of menu items doesn't show on gtk3.

Comment: It is not clear which GTK version you refer to. The question states Gtk3 but the syntax is for Gtk2. Please provide a complete minimal example to get more help.

Comment: @bohrax, thanks for comments. I solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last. I solved one of my questions again.

```
settings = gtk.Settings.get_default()
settings.set_property("gtk-menu-images", True) # this line allows to show images of menu items
```

Comment: Using GTK 2, I had to use `gtk.settings_get_default()` and that worked. I put this code in my "init" function separate from the GUI class. Thanks for this, it's hard to find information about GTK 2 anymore, but I have to make software for an old system.